# how to resolve the iOS deployment target issue in flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, dart

I am facing this issue related to `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`  while build the flutter application for the ios platform repeatedly, I am not able to understand how should I rectify it

```
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'firebase_core' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'firebase_auth' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'firebase_storage' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'firebase_messaging' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'firebase_analytics' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'cloud_functions' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'cloud_firestore' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')
```

my pod file for the ios flutter project is here

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

I checked the version setting after opening the project in xcode as well but was not able to understand how should i rectify this. Please guide how the IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET can be fixed

Answer (score 36):

In your `./ios/Podfile` uncomment:

```
# platform :ios, '9.0'
```

To

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

Replace the following to

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

by :

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Execute the following commands:

```
flutter clean 
flutter pub get
cd ios && pod install
```

Now

1. Build the project
2. Close and reopen Xcode

Comment: Normal User or Fresher in Flutter will not understand where to change this all things.

Comment: @PratikButani Change this in Flutter Project Directory ==> ios ==> Podfile

Comment: This, minus the `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)` line helped with a similar issue with Ionic

Comment: The source for flutter_additional_ios_build_settings can be found here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/4f9528293f54037993a6b2eb8f1df5604a3da954/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb . I don't think the Podfile should be messed with tbh.

Answer (score 4):

It's because all pods are not targeting iOS 9.0.

You can use this workaround in your `Podfile`

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: For flutter apps, `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)` should be added after line `installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|`.

Answer (score 0):

##### These warnings are apparently harmless. The following docs can be found within [the source for `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings()`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/4f9528293f54037993a6b2eb8f1df5604a3da954/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb):

> Suppress warning when pod supports a version lower than the minimum
> supported by Xcode (Xcode 12 - iOS 9).
> # This warning is harmless but confusing--it's not a bad thing for dependencies to support a lower version.

As a rule of thumb, I don't recommend messing with the Flutter build environment. You can update it from a new Flutter project, but don't put custom code in there unless absolutely necessary (which it usually isn't).